Java module cannot find folders from another module while installing their common parent module
I created a spring boot project and added 2 child modules to it: contract and infrastructure. Next, I added a dependency on the infrastructure to the contract module's pom to use classes from there. Everything is ok, idea sees classes from another module, but when I try to execute mvn install in parent module, I get errors like these:
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[ERROR] /Users/markhvostenko/IdeaProjects/cat-service/contract/src/main/java/com/catService/contract/dto/cat/CatDto.java:[12,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Color
  location: class com.catService.contract.dto.cat.CatDto
[ERROR] /Users/markhvostenko/IdeaProjects/cat-service/contract/src/main/java/com/catService/contract/commands/cat/IsOwnedByWithOwner.java:[3,46] package com.catService.infrastructure.entities does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/markhvostenko/IdeaProjects/cat-service/contract/src/main/java/com/catService/contract/commands/cat/IsOwnedByWithOwner.java:[5,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Owner
  location: class com.catService.contract.commands.cat.IsOwnedByWithOwner
[ERROR] /Users/markhvostenko/IdeaProjects/cat-service/contract/src/main/java/com/catService/contract/commands/owner/CreateOwner.java:[5,46] package com.catService.infrastructure.entities does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/markhvostenko/IdeaProjects/cat-service/contract/src/main/java/com/catService/contract/commands/owner/CreateOwner.java:[7,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class User
  location: class com.catService.contract.commands.owner.CreateOwner

Here is the repo: https://github.com/Marcelo20044/CatService.git
I tried to find a similar problem, but only found one from 6 years ago. There the problem was in using default packages, but I don’t seem to use those. I tried to do first mvn install directly in the infrastructure and then in the contract (using maven gui and terminal), but the error was the same.

It seems that your git repo does not contain all the files, could you verify this?

Your structure is wrong, because the src directory in the root location is wrong. You have to make a separate module maybe called app where you put your code into it... in that pom.xml you have to define deps to those other two modules... furthermore why having different java version defined in the children instead of using the configuration defined in parent? Really required?
